# ANTLR Throws error but grammar is functional

Tags: syntax-error, antlr, antlr4, rule

I have this grammar:

```
grammar Flow;

@header { import java.util.HashMap; }

@members { HashMap<String, String> vars = new HashMap<>(); }

WS:         (' '|'\n'|'\r'|'\t') -> skip;

flow:       (print|var)+ EOF;

print:      'print' (toPrint=PRINTABLE { System.out.println($toPrint.text); })|(id=ID {
    if (vars.containsKey($id.text)) {
        System.out.println(vars.get($id.text));
    } else {
        System.err.println("This variable is not assigned!");
    }
});

var:        'var' id=ID '=' val=PRINTABLE { vars.put($id.text, $val.text); };

PRINTABLE:  STRING|NUMBER|LETTER|DIGIT;

STRING:     '"' (.)*? '"';

fragment LETTER: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z');
fragment DIGIT:  ('0'..'9');

NUMBER:     DIGIT+ ('.' DIGIT+)?;

ID:         LETTER (LETTER|DIGIT)*;
```

When I invoke start rule 'flow' and enter some valid variable and try to print it, TestRig throws error:

line 2:6 missing PRINTABLE at 'output'

But all works nice.
How to block this annoying errors?

Thanks for feedback!

Comment: Could you post your sample input?

Comment: Btw. I'd make `PRINTABLE` a parser rule, i.e. `printable`. Otherwise there will be no tokens for `STRING`, `NUMBER` etc. since they will all end up being `PRINTABLE` tokens. Also a single character identifier will be a `PRINTABLE` and not an identifier since `PRINTABLE` comes first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a solution to your problem, but a slightly improved version of your grammar addressing the issues mentioned in my comment:

```
grammar Flow;

@header { import java.util.HashMap; }

@members { HashMap<String, String> vars = new HashMap<>(); }

WS:         (' '|'\n'|'\r'|'\t') -> skip;

flow:       (print|var)+ EOF;

print:        'print' (toPrint=printable { System.out.println($toPrint.text); })
            | (id=ID {
                      if (vars.containsKey($id.text)) {
                         System.out.println(vars.get($id.text));
                       } else {
                          System.err.println("This variable is not assigned!");
                       }
                     }
              )
            ;

var:        'var' id=ID '=' val=printable { vars.put($id.text, $val.text); };

printable:  STRING|NUMBER|ID|NUMBER;

STRING:     '"' (.)*? '"';

NUMBER:     DIGIT+ ('.' DIGIT+)?;

ID:         LETTER (LETTER|DIGIT)*;

fragment LETTER: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z');
fragment DIGIT:  ('0'..'9');
```